# Capturar duas partes de uma mesma string?

Tags: php

Tenho uma lista de nomes que seguem essa estrutura:

```
Diretoria: (aprovação 23, de 2014)
Diretoria: (aprovação 42, de 2015)
Diretoria: (aprovação 70, de 2016)
```

Como faço para capturar os números separadamente e coloca-los cada um em um `span`? para ficar assim:

```
Diretoria: (aprovação <span class="caixa_23">23</span>, de <span class="ano_2014">2014<span>)
Diretoria: (aprovação <span class="caixa_42">42</span>, de <span class="ano_2014">2015<span>)
Diretoria: (aprovação <span class="caixa_70">70</span>, de <span class="ano_2016">2014<span>)
```

Comment: Acho que poderia fazer buscas usando expressões regulares nas strings. Se elas seguem sempre esse formato `Diretoria: (aprovação X, de Y)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode usar a função [`preg_match`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.preg-match.php).

Supondo que a lista de nomes seja um `array` como esse:

```
$nomes = ['Diretoria: (aprovação 23, de 2014)',
          'Diretoria: (aprovação 42, de 2015)',
          'Diretoria: (aprovação 70, de 2016)'];

$spans = [];
```

Você pode fazer assim:

```
foreach ($nomes as $nome) {
    if (preg_match('/\(aprovação (\d+), de (\d+)\)/', $nome, $retorno) !== false) {
        $num = $retorno[1];
        $ano = $retorno[2];

        $spans[] = "Diretoria: (aprovação <span class=\"caixa_$num\">$num</span>, de <span class=\"ano_$ano\">$ano<span>)";
    }
}
```

Para mostrar o resultado:

```
foreach ($spans as $span) {
    echo $span . "\n";
}
```

<kbd>[Ver **DEMO**](http://ideone.com/zcY1LD)</kbd>